libstdc++ version conflict with mesa dri
I know the question seems to be similar to some other ones, but I think it is somewhat different. I am trying to launch a commercial application (ANSYS). I have installed all dependencies according to its documentation and now, when I try to launch it, it returns errors like this:
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /ansys_inc/v231/fluent/fluent23.1.0/lnamd64/syslib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so)

as it can be seen, the application tries to use its own libstdc++ library. The installed libstdc++ supports 3.4.26 (and also higher) version of GLIBCXX but the one in the application folder supports 3.4.25
I think I should change something in mesa library such that it needs version 25 or lower, but I don't know how?!

Maybe all you need to do is change the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to put the /usr/lib/dri before any others (if any). Your choice where to make the change, I like .profile for changing my whole environment, but project specific changes may be done in a project script.
